# ModRewrite реализация MVC

Tags: php, mvc, mod-rewrite

Сейчас у меня такой код где-то в классе `core`:

```
$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ( !empty($routes[1]) ) {
  $controller_name = $routes[1];
} elseif ( !empty($routes[2]) ) {
  $action_name = $routes[2];
}
```

В `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

После чего стартую контроллер с указанным именем и метод `actiion_name`.
Собственно, вопрос: а как обрабатываются ссылки более чем из двух частей?
Например `/event/today/morning/wakeup`.
Как в этом случае оформляется вызов контроллера? Я учусь, поэтому буду благодарен если кто-то объяснит что к чему.

Comment: модреврайт перенаправляет все запросы на index.php, а дальше заводится модуль роутинга/диспетчеризации, который по входящему урлу и указанным ему правилам сопоставления выясняет какой контроллер и action нужен.

Comment: @vitidev, Можете поподробнее про модуль диспетчеризации?   Благодарю

Comment: проще всего изучить любой mvc фреймворк чтобы понять как оно обычно все устроено. Берете любой фреймворк, документацию, раздел "routing/routes"  (можете прямо в гугл вбить "имя фреймворка routes" и смотрите примеры задания правил. Это даст понимание как другие решают сопоставление урла с конечной целью даже без чтения чужого кода